# Автоматическая табуляция в NotePad++

Tags: редактор-текста, html, notepad++

Очень часто, работая в `NotePad++`, приходится вручную табулировать `html`-файл. В принципе, это занимает всего 1-2 минуты, но сумарно затрачивается некое время, которое можно продуктивно использовать на благо работы `:)`

Есть ли какая-то функция/плагин, который автоматически табулирует `html`-файл?

---

Например:

```
<!-- до -->
<html>
<head>
<title>
name
</title>
</head>
<body>
text
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<!-- после -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            name
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        text
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для написания кода можете использовать плагин NppAutoIndent(довольно удобно), для автоматического табулирования файлов вы можете использовать плагин IdentByFold.

После установки плагина - открываем "плохой файл", жмем -

```
 Плагины->Ident By Fold->Reindent File
```

И файл становится хорошим =)

Comment: Большое спасибо, попробую :)

Comment: Пользуйтесь на здоровье =)

Comment: Еще вопрос: а возможно ли настроить, что-бы при вставке текста с буфера обмена, он автоматически обрабатывался функций `Reindent File`?

Comment: AlexWindHope, ***** тебе СПАСИБО!!! Обновил Plugin Manager и через него скачал оба плагина. Искал нечто подобное, т.к. до этого куски HTMLя приходилось вручную табулировать, а это как никак по 300-400 строк только кода, не считая текст. Еще раз СПАСИБО!

Comment: Не могу найти плагин Ident By Fold

Comment: Что за на... почему я пытаюсь сделать табуляцию в файле посредством выполнения плагина идентбайфолд (как указано во втором примере файла), а он делает все да наоборот, выравнивает по левому краю без табуляции (как в первом примере кода)!!!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ffes/indentbyfold

Это прямая ссылка на плагин .

Ставить сюда :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Plugins\ или сюда :

C:\Program Files\Notepad++\Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Автоформатирование html - зло. Особенно когда inline-блоки попадутся.